# Resource temporarily unavailable. Authentication by key failed (Error -18). (Error #35)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-ec2, robo3t

I'm using EC2 Amazon Web Service to launch my server using NodeJS, MongoDB.

I completed to save and load the data using my android application through NodeJS server and MongoDB but when I tried to check the data using RoboMongo (Robo 3T), the error occurred.

Resource temporarily unavailable. Authentication by key (path of the .pem key) failed (Error -18). (Error #35)

[Robomongo 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3dfr.png)

[Robomongo 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fxe1.png)

[Error dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsH18.png)

This is what I did in Robomongo.
These are the result of searching the google... I think I did right...
What is wrong?

Answer (score -2):

I Solved the problem myself. 
When you have this problem,

**1. Check out /etc/mongod.conf**
In network interfaces.
bindIP must be 0.0.0.0
not 127.0.0.1

**2. Check the SSH User Name.** 
For an Amazon Linux AMI, the user name is ec2-user.
For the others, Check out the link ! https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html

**3. If it didn't help,** 
try to download what developer uploaded (1.2 - Beta)
https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/issues/1189#issuecomment-353279070

Comment: This answer is irrelevant because ssh connection has not been even established.